# Properties from C# DLL dont exist from Visual Basic

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, properties

There is a console application done in C# which has a code that goes like this:

```
Settings.Ciphering=something.
```

I have to build the same (desktop) project but using visual basic and i cannot have access to Ciphering simple because it doesn't exist.

I have referenced a DLL made on C# in my Visual Basic project but although some properties from  Settings are available to be used like:

```
Settings.Password= ´something,
```

there is a property which I don't access because it doesn't exist(I checked, it doesn't exist)

From Visual Basic: Settings its a ReadOnlyProperty that returns an object class
From C# (originally created)Settings its just like this :

```
public GXDLMSSettings Settings
```

Comment: See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object?force_isolation=true and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/how-to-change-user-settings?force_isolation=true

Comment: after referencing have you tried to import it? usually it doesn't matter from which language it comes.

Comment: Some of what you are looking for may be in the VisualBasic namespace.  Don't be scared; you can use that from C#